# Unbind click event for dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link on the page which gets created dynamically and does a redirect . I want to stop that and show my popup once clicked. I am able to bind my click event using jQuery `.on(...)`.

After showing the popup it still redirects.  How can I stop from redirecting event?

I tried

1. `event.preventDefault();`
2. `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`
3. `event.stopPropagation();`
4. and `return false;`

Nothing worked. Please help.

This is my code snippet to bind click event to the dynamic element.

$(document).on('click','a.custom',function(event){

/* tried them both , it still redirects */

event.preventDefault();

event.stopImmediatePropagation();

});

Comment: how did you use `.on()`? share your completer code for the event handling...

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/pc2tx1us/5/)

```
<a class="customerResultIndex">Click Me</a>

$(function(){
    $('.customerResultIndex').on('click',function(){
        openCustomerOverlay();
    })

});
function openCustomerOverlay(){
    var node = "Hi Mr";

    var overlayContainer = 
    '<div class="customerOverlayShadow">'+
        '<div class="customerOverlay borderRadius10px">'+
            '<h2 class="customerPopHeading">-- </h2>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>';

    $("body").prepend(overlayContainer).focus();
    $('.customerPopHeading').text(node);

};
```